# Why are requests throttled for more time than specified in the middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

I have my routes declared like this:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'media', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:120,1'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'MediaController@index'); // <-- Route in question
        Route::delete('/{id}', 'MediaController@delete');
        Route::patch('/{id}', 'MediaController@edit');
    });
    Route::post('/', 'MediaController@upload')->middleware('throttle:100,1440');
});
```

If I understand the throttling middleware correctly, when user hits the rate limiting (120 requests in 1 minute) he should be throttled for the remaining time of the 1 minute period and then unblocked.

However, the blocking time is higher than 1 minute. See `retry-after` header:
[image: Returned retry-after header value is 180]

(When I first noticed it, it was more than 600 seconds so it's not always 180 seconds)

Any ideas why would it be higher than 1 minute?

Comment: Try throttle 120,0 and reply the results.

Comment: @user8555937 `x-ratelimit-remaining` stays at 120 all the time and requests aren't throttled

Comment: The 120 says something about the amount of requests which can be made before hitting the throttle limit. It does not specify the 'punishment' for exceeding it.

Comment: Exactly. I'm just wondering how is it possible that setting it to `120,1` can have a greater 'punishment` than 1 minute.

Comment: I've done some more testing and it looks like the problem is that I have different throttling configs for different routes. And like you can see here, the upload route has a throttling period of 24 hours, and once the user hits it, he will be locked out of all routes for the specified period. I need to do more testing but it looks like the throttling is not route specific, like I thought it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Turns out the default behavior for the `throttle` middleware doesn't work per route. It just throttles requests per logged in user. And as you can see I had one route (the upload one) that has `throttle:100,1440`, and this caused problems resulting in much longer "punishments" even for routes with `throttle:120,1`.

**My solution:**
I wrote my own version of the `ThrottleRequests.php` middleware that works per route:

1. Place [this file](https://gist.github.com/lukaszmtw/a92c9ef1bcaadd49fb51405f6b522c7c) in your `app/Http/Middleware` folder.
2. In `app/Http/Kernel.php` change your throttle route middleware to the new one:

```
'throttle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsPerRoute::class,
```

3. Now whenever you assign a `throttle` middleware it will work per route.

**Another solution:**
You can also use the default middleware and make use of the 3rd parameter. You can pass a prefix parameter like that: `throttle:100,1440,upload`. It will assign the upload prefix to the throttling key and rate limit the requests based on that. However, to achieve per route rate limiting you would have to assign a different prefix for each route.

Answer (score 0):

The `retry-after` header has nothing to do with rate-limiting. All headers related to rate-limiting are prefixed with `x-ratelimit-`. The header `x-ratelimit-reset` is what you're looking for: a timestamp of when the limit will be reset. This should be within the next minute (or whatever period you set it to)